# Is it okay to delete RabbitMQ's `/` VHost?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

In our environment, we have several RabbitMQ VHosts defined: one for `dev`, one for `qa`, one for `staging` and so on. The default VHost `/` is unused and shows no users as having access, nor does it have any exchanges or queues defined.

Is it okay to run `rabbitmqctl delete_vhost '/'` to remove this VHost? Does rabbitmq-server or any of the clients place any special meaning on it, or break if it is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Special meaning of `/` vhost is the default vhost, which clients will be connecting to if other vhost is not specified.

It's safe to delete it, if there are no clients connecting to it. 
But you should make sure you have configured all plugins (like MQTT or STOMP if you use them) to use your custom vhosts.

Or you can just leave it be, since no users have access to it anyway.